# add_faiss_index import unkown | what should i import or install to use add_faiss_index

Tags: faiss, semantic-search

## using faiss to add index embeddings

embeddings_dataset.add_faiss_index(column='embeddings')

I have error while loading this code because I don't know what to import to use add_faiss_index,
I tried importing faiss ,
also tired from datasets.Dataset import add_faiss_index it isnot valid and I don't find any good documentation to understand please help

I tried using add_faiss_index() functions but unable to use it since I am unaware of what to import